# I am making the bible app and I want to print a particular chapter and highlight a particular line

Tags: java

I am trying to do same in Eclipse to print a text file and highlight a particular line, but am only able to read text file and not the line in it. Following is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Bible {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("temp.txt");
            int character;

            while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) character);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not the line in it"? Do you want to print a line number? Or do you want to read lines from the FileStream instead of a characters?

Comment: i want to print one complete line from a given text file for example i have two lines like:-   1. This is Stack Over flow.  2.Java is a good language....., then i want to print complete second line

Comment: In this case the readLine() from a BufferedReader wrapped over a FileReader will work, as in the answers below

Answer (score 2):

Correct code to read a file line by line is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {
            //br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now comes the code to highlight.

There are multiple options to do it.

Use html codes in file e.g.

```
origString = origString.replaceAll(textToHighlight,"<font color='red'>"+textToHighlight+"</font>");
```

Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(origString));

Use spannable texts

```
String  text = "Test"; 
Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 14, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spanText);
```

Use some third party library
    [EmphasisTextView](https://github.com/athkalia/EmphasisTextView) and 
    [Android TextView Link Builder](https://github.com/klinker24/Android-TextView-LinkBuilder)

Comment: I feel the highlight part will be complicated to used since we don't really now on what client this is supposed to run. `Bible app` could means Android but not necessarly, we have a java class with a `public static void main` so it could be on Swing instead. But the idea is there and should be usable in most API